# Would Java annotation impact runtime performance?

Tags: java, performance, annotations

We know that annotation would cause component scan during startup, but would it impact the runtime performance once all configuration loaded?

Btw, we're building a homegrown lightweight restful service framework, to config routing, we got 2 styles:

- hard coded enums

  annotation

One of our colleagues has performance concerns about annotation.

Comment: A relevant blog post: http://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, the annotations add a couple of milliseconds at run-time. Once the program is running, however, there will be no additional overhead. Before you optimise, it is **always** a good idea to run the program to check if performance speed is even an issue - if it ain't broken, don't fix it.

If the program is running too slowly, I would wager that the bottleneck isn't the annotations. To optimise it you should write some benchmarking code to find where the bottleneck actually is and optimise the slowest part. Your colleague would better off saving time by running everywhere and eating his food raw than optimising his annotations.

Comment: Could you please explain why it expenses those extra milliseconds?

Comment: It really depends on how you are using your annotations. Because annotations are essentially just metadata in your class files, they are often used to tell java how to use your class with other libraries and files (like XML Schemas: [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/package-summary.html). When you want to compile your program, java has to map your annotations to your class files, which involves a small number of relatively fast operations. This is where the delay comes from.

Comment: It is also worth noting that using annotations properly can even speed up your programs. Java will automatically try and optimise certain parts of your code when it compiles your program. If you specify these optimisations with annotations ahead of time, you can save java the trouble of figuring it out on runtime. [link](http://www.cs.ucsb.edu/~ckrintz/papers/PLDI-01-Annot.pdf). This is not likely something that you have to worry about, however, unless it is absolutely critical that your program runs as fast as possible.